# Excel Cell References in Sum Formula with Multiple Condition Array

Tags: arrays, excel, pivot-table

Is it possible to put cell references inside an array that is being used with in a GetPivotData formula, encapsulated by a SUM?

For example, this formula works

```
=SUM(GETPIVOTDATA("loss_pct",Pres3_Pivot!$A$1,"typeOfLiquidation",{"REO Sale","Short Sale"},"liquidationMonth",E$6))
```

It take the sum of the GetPivotData result for the "typeofLiquidation" values "REO Sale" and "Short Sale"

This formula does not work:

```
=SUM(GETPIVOTDATA("loss_pct",Pres3_Pivot!$A$1,"typeOfLiquidation",{D23,D24},"liquidationMonth",E$6))
```

This attempts the same result, but with cell references at 'D23' and 'D24.' Attempting to enter this formula is met with an application error telling me the formula I typed contains an error.

This also does not work, but this time at least I get a reference error:

```
=SUM(GETPIVOTDATA("loss_pct",Pres3_Pivot!$A$1,"typeOfLiquidation",INDIRECT({"D23","D24"}),"liquidationMonth",E$6))
```

Does anyone have a suggestion? Is such a reference inside the array possible?

Comment: yeah, I can't see to get that to work either. I'm considering writing a function in VBA to get the inputs of the cells into a string of {"ref1","ref2",etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution.

This formula works (entered as an array [Ctrl+Shft+Enter]):

```
=SUM(GETPIVOTDATA("loss_pct",Pres3_Pivot!$A$1,"typeOfLiquidation",U23:U24,"liquidationMonth",E$6))
```

The key was referencing cells U23:U24 where I can transformed the actual references (D23:D24) into Text(). This was a requirement for the GetPivotData to work even without the sum and the array component.

Entered as an array formula (Ctrl+Shft+Enter), it works. Thanks pnuts!